# What is the difference between ChannelGroup and ArrayList<Channel>?

Tags: java, netty

I am using Netty 4.x and I wonder what is the difference between.

```
ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup (GlobalEventExecutor.INSTANCE);
```

and

```
ArrayList<Channel> channels = new ArrayList<>()
```

Comment: Maybe you can clarify what you mean; as the questions currently stands, it is like asking the difference between an apple and a car

Comment: @Daniele Your comparison is really to broad, its more like the difference between a `HashSet` and an `EnumSet`, as a `ChannelGroup` is more like a specialized "list" class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ChannelGroup` is basically an "enhanced" list.

With a normal Java list, you have to manually deregister channels when they close, a `ChannelGroup` does this for you

You need to manually loop over a normal java list if you want to send a message, but a `ChannelGroup` comes with its own write method., Like:

```
ChannelGroup recipients = ...;
recipients.write(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(
     "Service will shut down for maintenance in 5 minutes.",
     CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
```

Using a `ChannelGroup` basically makes your life easier, as it comes with so many utility methods, an example from the [javadoc](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup.html) for closing:

```
recipients.close().awaitUninterruptibly();
```

If you want to close all channels when using an `ArrayList`, you need to loop over all channels, call their close methods, and loop again and wait for their close futures, making sure you never modify the list while looping